# Printf and C++ strings

Tags: c++, string, printf, c-str

So I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> strs;
    strs.push_back("happy");    
    const string& a1 = strs[0];
    strs.push_back("birthday");
    const string& a2 = strs[1];
    strs.push_back("dude");
    const string& a3 = strs[2];

    printf("%s\n", a1.c_str());     
    return 0;
}
```

which is pretty straightforward but it doesn't work.
The *printf* doesn't print anything.
It does print if I change it to:

```
const string& a1 = strs[0].c_str();
```

can someone please explain the behavior of it.

Comment: Read the doc on [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back), particularly the part about : "If the new `size()` is greater than `capacity()` then all iterators **and references** (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated."

Comment: If you don't want your references to be invalidated, reserve space in advance, e.g. `strs.reserve(16); // reserve space for 16 elements`.

Answer (score 8):

Your calls to `push_back` potentially (and in your case obviously actually) invalidate all references into the `vector`, namely if the `vector` is too small to store the new element. You thus cannot use any references into the `vector` created before a `push_back` unless you make sure that the `vector`s capacity is big enough.

If you make sure that the `vector` has enough capacity for all the elements (i.e. by using `std::vector::reserve`) *before* you create the references, your first version will work as expected.

Your second example works because you create a new, temporary `string` (which has its lifetime extended to the lifetime of the reference) the reference binds to.

Answer (score 1):

```
strs.push_back("happy");    
const string& a1 = strs[0];
```

Your reference is valid upto this point. The following push_back however creates problems

```
strs.push_back("birthday");
```

This increases the capacity of the vector from 1 to 2.
Since the new capacity is greater than the old capacity, all references (as well as iterators) created uptill this point on the vector get invalidated.

As a side note,
The c_str gives you a char* (\0 terminated string). 
If your insertion was of the form

```
strs.push_back("happ\0y");
const string& a1 = strs[0].c_str();
```

a1 would have the value 'happ'